# ArangoDB Import csv to edge (Graph)

Tags: csv, graph, import, arangodb, edge-list

I have a csv file that I want to import into a graph in ArangoDB.
I'm using ArangoDB3-3.1.24 community version.

Here are the first three rows of the csv file

```
id,_from,_to,score
1,568703.1,568703.2,282
2,568703.1,568703.31,183
3,568703.1,568703.91,238
```

And here is what I tried

```
arangoimp --file "C:\Users\M\Desktop\file.csv" --server.username root --type csv --collection "Col_edge_L"
```

I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 5):

If the edge collection doesn't already exist then you'll need to also pass the params `--create-collection true --create-collection-type edge`.

It could also be that the file may not be accessible to `arangoimp` - it may not have sufficient permissions to access the user's desktop. Try moving it to somewhere like `c:\temp` and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm presuming an edge collection `_from` and `_to` should structure like a `vertex_collection_name/collection_key`. Try something like _to='geo/568703.1`. I'm not sure though.